# Should I use "shall", or "let's"?

Tags: grammar

Today when it was about time to go home, my English teacher asked me to lead my friends to pray in English. I led them by saying "Let's pray together!" However, my teacher told me that I was wrong and I should've just said "Shall we pray together.". Despite that, I'm unsure whether I was wrong. So, was I really wrong to say "Let's pray together"?

Comment: He said: " There are  just some things which can not be translated literally.". He compared it to "tidak apa-apa" in Bahasa, which is if we literally translate it to English will be "no what what" which doesn't make sense, and it should have been translated to "it's okay".

Comment: _Tidak apa2_ would translate nicely into many English lects with that same sense. And _shall_ is rarely used in modern English. In America, there are only two constructions it occurs in. One is _Shall we `VP`?_ which is an invitation, as noted. The other is _Shall I `VP`?_ which is an offer. Both are rare and limited to special occasions. _Let's_, on the other hand, is very common and completely grammatical. It's a fixed contraction, like _tak_ for _tidak_, and has almost as many uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The teacher has given an instruction as an elderly man.
"Let's pray" is rather an order like, "shall we pray" is like a request, implying we shall pray only with your concurrence.

Answer (score 2):

No you was not wrong to say let's pray together.

let's --> let us

let us pray together

It makes perfect sense grammatically. It's an invitation to pray together. Maybe find a new English teacher!